# Unique solution of Euler-Lagrange equations joining two points

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I am reading the introduction to [Variational Integrators](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/bib/2001/09-MaWe2001/MaWe2001.pdf) by Marsden and West and I see that the starting point to build the discrete Lagrangian is the theorem that states that for any two close enough points $q_0$, $q_1$ and time $h$ small enough, there exists a unique Lagrangian movement $q(t)$ with $q(0)=q_0$ and $q(h)=q_1$. This is remindful of the existence of local geodesics, just we do not have a metric here, since the context is that of abstract differentiable manifolds.

They give [Marsden and Ratiu](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387986432) as a reference for the proof of this theorem, but I am unable to find this exact statement. Maybe it is hidden into a more general fact. I would appreciate if you point out the particular page of this or another text, or provide a proof of this seemingly elementary fact.

Feel free to ask for clarifications.